# failed.org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: String, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(db col name)

Tags: hibernate, hbm

I am using Net Beans IDE , When i start to deploy my web project it shows me at the console output an error says:

```
failed.org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: String, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(db col name)
```

From the message it can not convert types ; I tried to check the types in my files .hbm and .java but no luck so far .

The property for which this error is being thrown is defined as

```
<property name="exemptionOwnerName1" type="String">
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason is , hibernate tries to convert the types but one of them was in compatible

my code was string like this

```
<property name="exemptionOwnerName1" type="String">
```

and it should by with small letter `s`

```
 <property name="exemptionOwnerName1" type="string">
```

seems its case sensitive and in *hbm* it should be **string** and in *java* class **String**

[Property documentation for type](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-property)

Answer (score 0):

This is important to remember that while declaring String in pojo class we use "String", and in hibernate.hbm.file "string".

same for Date datatype in pojo class "Date" and in mapping file "date".